# How to get mobile number from facebook login using jquery?

Tags: facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk, facebook-login

I am trying to  work facebook login with javascript but there are some issue faces. If facebook user register with email id then it gets email id but when user register with mobile phone then how can I get mobile_phone?

```
FB.api('/me', 'GET',  {fields: 'email,name,id'},function(response) {
                console.log(response);
                var id = response.id;
                var name = response.name;
                var email = response.email;

    }, {scope: 'email',return_scopes: true});
```

here is my code.
Please help me on this.
thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> then how can I get mobile_phone?

You can’t.

Facebook does not let normal 3rd-party apps access a user’s mobile number via Graph API.

(You might have seen stuff like the login dialog from Uber, they show the phone number there. But that is because they have some sort of special deal with Facebook that enables them to do this.)

Comment: But, When select out apps that time can we get phone number, is it possible?

Comment: I don’t understand what you are trying to ask.

Comment: Well as I said, _you can not get it._

Comment: @sarveshDineshkumarPatel it's not a way to ask someone who is trying to answer your question